# GIL in standalone executables

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gil

I am not thoroughly sure in how GIL is implemented, but in theory, if I was to compile a python script into exe using [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/), would it still have GIL implemented? Any way to bypass that?

Comment: I was talking about standard Python.3 however. Would the executable be any faster if I used Cython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIL will be there, if you are using CPython (the "standard Python"). Pyinstaller does not compile, but [bundles the Python script, its dependencies, **and the interpreter**](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html) in use in the executable. Because of that the standard ways to bypass GIL apply:

- C extensions and [Cython code](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#nogil) may release the GIL while not manipulating interpreter state or Python objects, or [calling Python/C API functions](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock).
- Divide the work between [multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).